# Serial voting reversed, but not all

Tags: support, bug, downvotes, serial-voting

Yesterday, someone has downvoted me 17 times, just at the end of the UTC day and continued today. The voting was caught by the reversal job at 3 am, but it only caught the votes from today and didn't reverse the 2 votes from yesterday. Is this a bug? Why were the 2 votes from before midnight not reversed?

[image]

This is the Q/A which was not reversed:
[Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808332/should-we-ever-check-for-mysqli-connect-errors-manually)

Comment: 2 DVs is not enough to trigger the script.  Time to alert a moderator about it.

Comment: @HansPassant Except that neither the question nor answer linked have downvotes (either already reversed automatically or a mod stepped in)

Comment: No downvotes on there that I can see. Perhaps the reputation view hasn't caught up yet? [Just blame caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I can't see the downvotes anymore either. I could see them at the time of posting this question. I see no new even in reputation view. I will blame caching and will revisit this tomorrow. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: All 17 votes have been reversed, but the reputation page still shows only +30 reversal.